# Scheme for custom fields on issue types

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a kinda scheme that is a list of custom fields and apply this scheme to an issue type.

This would cause that issue type to have all custom fields in the list.

I know you have to first associate the field with a screen and also a field configuration. But its this last step 'project and issue type scope' that is confusing me.

The only way I could see how to do this is to go into EACH custom field, then go to the CONTEXTS for that field, then add a new context associating the field and the issue type.

Field configurations and field configuration schemes don't seem to do the trick. It still seems a necessary condition to have your custom field associated with an issue type, but you still need to do that step above, to create a new context for each custom field.

I'm wondering if there is a way to group all the fields in a scheme and associate that scheme once instead of having to do it for EACH FIELD.

Am I missing something? Or it's just not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Issue Type Screen Scheme.
First create a default screen with the fields for issue type X. You can also create screens for Create and Edit too if you want
Then define a Screen Scheme for issue type X which says which of those screens to use for that issue type.
Then create an Issue Type Screen Scheme (ITSS) that uses the Screen Scheme for issue type X

It is convoluted but does work. Don't use Field Configurations unless you need to make the field required, and even then it's better to use a Validator on a transition. The only time you need a custom field context is if you have select lists with different sets of options for different projects. If possible, avoid using issue types in custom field contexts.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! - but I'm confused. In the screenshot above, you can see there is a green checkmark next to 'Field Screen'. How does this screen setup differ from what you've proposed?

Comment: Field screen refers to the first part where you create a screen and add fields to it. This is how Jira can allow different sets of fields for each issue type

Comment: Best thing here is to find a Jira instance that isn't production and play with it for a bit. Then write down each bit of knowledge you have reverse engineered out it :)